# How to convert type 'int' to 'unityengine.gameobject'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a script that controls respawn system of the checkpoint. In PlayerController script, I declared "health" as public int. Then, I refered "health" from it in this script. So, if player dies (health = 0), it will respawn at the checkpoint.

However, when I refer 'health' in this script, I have to convert 'int' to 'unityengine.gameobject'. Can anyone help me please. I just started to learn C#.

```
public class PlayerPros : MonoBehaviour
{
    private savePoint sp;
    private GameObject health;


    private void Start()
    {
        health = GetComponent<GameObject>();
        sp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SP").GetComponent<savePoint>();
        transform.position = sp.lastCheckPointPos;
    }

   private void Update()
    {

       if ( health = 0) //error occurs here
       {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `health = 0`means that you assign the value to the variable. You probably mean equals: `health == 0`

Comment: `GameObject` is no component either .. do you rather mean `gameObject` the property that gives you the `GameObject` this script is attached to? And well the error should be pretty self explanatory .. a `GameObject` is no `int` ... Are you trying to access a different component via `GetComponent` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't convert the type, you get the variable form the class.

If the 2 scripts are on the same Gameobject you can use

`int health = GetComponent<PlayerController >().health;`

make sure that your health variable in the `PlayerController` script is public

Also you can't do `if ( health = 0)`
the correct way is `if ( health == 0)`